# PyQt: How to prevent processing multiple resize events when maximizing a window?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap

I have a `QMainWindow` containing a child `QWidget` containing itself a `QLabel`.

When the window is maximized (e.g. by clicking the maximize icon on the window), the `QLabel.resizeEvent()` handler is called multiple times (supposedly to follow the progressive enlargement of the window until it takes the full desktop space).

The code in the event handler calls `setPixmap()` to scale the label pixmap. This is a relatively long operation which slows the process. Code for the label:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QFrame, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImageReader, QPixmap

class DisplayArea(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pix_map = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;")

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.pix_map = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.scale_image(self.size())

    def scale_image(self, size):
        if self.pix_map is None:
            return

        scaled = self.pix_map.scaled(size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setPixmap(scaled)

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        self.scale_image(e.size())
        super().resizeEvent(e)
```

Is there a possibility to process the event only once, when the window has reached its final size?

Comment: The question is: how to know that size no longer change at least for a certain period of time?

Comment: @eyllanesc: My need is to scale the label pixmap when the window is resized, but I discovered this strange effect when the window is maximized. During a manual resizing, the handler is called fewer times, it's ok. So yes your rephrasing is correct.

Comment: How many times is it called when it is maximized and how often? In my case(Linux, PyQt5 5.11.3) I do not observe what you point out to me but I have an idea, but its operation depends on the data I ask

Comment: @eyllanesc: 160 times for a single click on maximize.

Comment: and how often does the maximized average take?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I'd say it takes 0.8s for the 160 calls.

Comment: okay, with my idea I'll just call it 8 times, my initial version had a problem, try the current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the resizeEvent is called many times in the time that the window is maximized, and that same number of times is what you call scale_image. One possible possible is not to update unless a period of time passes. In the following example only resizes for times greater than 100 ms (the time you must calibrate):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class DisplayArea(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self._flag = False
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;")

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.scale_image()

    def scale_image(self):
        if self.pix_map.isNull():
            return
        scaled = self.pix_map.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setPixmap(scaled)

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        if not self._flag:
            self._flag = True
            self.scale_image()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: setattr(self, "_flag", False))
        super().resizeEvent(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    da = DisplayArea()
    da.set_image(QtGui.QImage("logo.png"))
    w.setCentralWidget(da)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```